# How can I change my custom toolbar icon dynamically

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In my application I'm using `toolbar` which  having `imageview` in it. I need to change that imageview dynamically .

Here is my **toolbar.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionBarImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
        android:src="@drawable/forewarn"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is toolbar declaration in activity:

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
final ImageView imageInToolbar = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.actionBarImage);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

//            getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.abc);
        }
```

here is my actual toolbar  :

[image: here is my actual toolbar image :]

my required toolbar with dynamic change of imageview :

[image: toolbar with dynamic change]

Comment: You have the imageview reference of the toolbar. What is the problem in changing that imageview src ?

Comment: `imageInToolbar.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc));`

Comment: im getting my image source as like this : image_01.jpg i need to load that image source and need to apply on my toolbar.

Comment: @LaxmanRosy are you getting this from web service? means from server side

Comment: yes im getting my image source from server side , according to that image source i need to apply for perticular user image.

Comment: @LaxmanRosy the you will need whole url to load that image not only the image_01.jpg.

Comment: @LaxmanRosy try my updated answer. but in this you need a url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018662/how-can-i-change-my-custom-toolbar-icon-dynamically/48018702#comment83006224_48018662) Try this :

```
final ImageView imageInToolbar = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.actionBarImage);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
imageInToolbar.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(th‌​is, R.drawable.abc));
```

For loading image from server :

For [Glide](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/) use :

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(url) 
     .into(imageInToolbar);
```

In gradle : `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'`

For picasso use :

```
Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(imageInToolbar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_arrow));
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```